# ASP (VBscript) radio buttons not returning value

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have 2 very simple pages, an HTML page and a classic ASP page .. the html page has a form which calls (and sends) the data to the ASP form (which then prints out the data)

The problem is I'm not getting the value of the radio button, I'm simply just getting "on".

Here is the html:

```
<form action="form.asp" method="post">
    <strong>Gender:</strong>
    <input type="radio" value"male" name="gender">Man
    <input type="radio" value"female" name="gender">Woman<p></p>
    <strong>Size:</strong>
    <input type="text" width="20" name="size" size="4"><p></p>
    <strong>Color:</strong>
    <select size="1" name="color">
        <option>blue</option>
        <option>green</option>
        <option>black</option>
    </select><p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Order">
</form>
```

and here is the ASP

```
<%
Dim strgen, strsize, strcol
strgen = Request.form("gender")
intsize = Request.form("size")
strcol = Request.form("color")
Response.write "Your gender: " & strgen & "<br />"
Response.write "Your size: " & intsize & "<br />"
Response.write "The color you ordered: " & strcol & "<br />"
```

%>

Like I said, all I'm getting for "strgen" is "on" ...

Comment: Is there perhaps an onsubmit event on the form that might be altering the data before submission ?

Comment: Something complete different: I can't understand why this question has received an upvote ? The answer is that it is a typo (to be confirmed by Kevin). This is a legal question, but not a question interesting enough for others, it it? Although it must be asked here (that's where we are here for), in order to receive an answer, I don't find it's important enough to warrant an upvote.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are on about Edelcom, but thanks to AUSteve ... it was a typo - these things happen!

Comment: Yes Kevin, it was a typo, and a valid question. I'm not saying that. I'm glad that your problem is solved. Being a developer myself, I know how long you can overlook such small typos. I just thought that up votes mark a question as being important for other programmers too. A question like yours does not fall under that category and therfore does not deserve a up vote. Mind you, that is just my opinion. Best luck with your site, but please try some sort of html validator. It will save you countless hours in the end (at least it does to me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's typos in your code, missing equals sign.

```
value"male"
```

should be

```
value="male"
```

Because the value was ignored it was returning the default value of "on"

Comment: Please use an html validator (search for them via google) before posting such questions. It will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an html validator as [www.htmlvalidator.com](http://www.htmlvalidator.com/). This site offers a free one which is good (I'm using the professional version myself).

This will find such types immediatly (and will save you countless hours of searching).